# Youtube downloader: illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, video, youtube

I am working on a Youtube downloader, I use `Path.combine` but when I launch my program and place an url in the field I got this error:

> illegal characters in path

```
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar.Maximum = 100;
        if (!(txturl.Text == string.Empty))
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(txturl.Text);
                VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(cmbResolution.Text));
                if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                    DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
                VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, video.Title + video.VideoExtension));
                downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { IsBackground = true };
                thread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception yt) { MessageBox.Show(yt.Message); }
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Input field cannot be empty."); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `"\\"`, as Path.Combine() puts them in for you.

**EDIT:**

Example: `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "hello");` returns something like `C:\path\to\exe\hello\`

Comment: Thanks, but still refuse to work. Please can't I use something like "Directory GetCurrentDirectory", Please don't mind my mistake.

Comment: Try this: `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, string.Format("{0}.{1}", video.Title, video.VideoExtension));`

Comment: I've copied the whole code here, please help me review and debug it. Thanks sir

Comment: Just for debugging, add this beneath the VideoDownloader call: `MessageBox.Show(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, string.Format("{0}.{1}", video.Title, video.VideoExtension)));`

Comment: Jean Luc Nürrenberg, Thank You very much sir. It now work for me. It the Youtube Url that i copied but now i have try another url and it get downloaded.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: please help this second time, My progress bar increase accordingly but my lblPercentage.Text refuse to update in my invoke method. That's why i commented it.

`progressBar.Value = (int)e.ProgressPercentage;
                //lblPercentage.Text=$"{string.Format("{0:0.##}", e.ProgressPercentage)}%";
                progressBar.Update();`

Comment: Try `lblPercentage.Text = string.Format("{0}%", e.ProgressPercentage);`

Comment: ok thanks, I used e.ProgressPercentage.ToString(); i will use this now. 
Why is it that most of the youtube links i copied throw that exception error?

Comment: I've discover something, any video that contain this characters "/, \, |" and some others are the one giving me problem.